# JavaScript in server does not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#musteri_sno").change(function () {
            var strSayacID = "";
            strSayacID = $(this)[0].value; // get the selected state id

            var url = "/SayacOkumalari/MusteriSayaclariniGetir/" + strSayacID;
            // call controller's action
            $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
                // do something once the data is retrieved
                $("#sayac_no").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                    $("#sayac_no").append("<option value='"
                     + optionData.sno
                     + "'>" + optionData.sayac_seri_no
                     + "</option>");
                });
            });
        })
    .change(); // making sure the event runs on initialization for default value
    });
    </script>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SayacSecimiPartial", "SayacOkumalari", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div_grafik" }, new { id="sayac_secimi_form"}))
    {
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("musteri_sno", (SelectList)ViewBag.musteri_id, "--Müşteri Seçiniz--", new { id = "musteri_sno" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("sayac_no", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Sayaç Seçiniz --", new { id = "sayac_no" })
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Uygula" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
}
```

This script works on localhost but it does not work on server. There are a lot of script in my project and all of them are working too. Only this script does not work. I cant find, Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked in the console to see if the JSON request has been made successfully? I suspect it'll be a URL problem

Comment: ali -that was 'cruel' deselecting my answer as the 'answer' :). being serious, i think the one you've chosen does a disservice to anyone looking for a solid answer to this type of problem as it may well work in your instance but is certainly not a bulletproof solution beyond that. not looking to have mine reinstated as 'pick' but be aware that the @Url.Action() method will ALWAYS resolve the url relative to the structure of your hosting environment, whereas your current 'pick' is so fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = "/SayacOkumalari/MusteriSayaclariniGetir/" + strSayacID;
```

Instead of this try using the following as I have a doubt on the folder structure in your solution.

```
var url = "../SayacOkumalari/MusteriSayaclariniGetir/" + strSayacID;
```

Let me know if it doesn't helps, I'll give a try for another thing.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem line is this one here:

```
var url = "/SayacOkumalari/MusteriSayaclariniGetir/" + strSayacID;
```

try changing this to:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("MusteriSayaclariniGetir", "SayacOkumalari", new {Id = strSayacID })';
```

As you don't show the controller action, I'm 'assuming' that `MusteriSayaclariniGetir` has a parameter called `Id`. If not, then simply change the `new {Id = strSayacID })` section to match the parameter name that's required.